# Change font tabular for a specific row

Tags: tables, fonts, tabularx

I am using tabular to create a table in latex. You can see my work below:

In this I need to change the font for the 2nd row to Courier font.

How can I achieve this. I do not want to change the font for the rest of the rows, specially the header.

Thanks!

My Work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|l|}
        \hline 
        \rowcolor[HTML]{CACFD2} 
        \textbf{Header 1} & \textbf{Header 2} & \textbf{Header 3} \\ \hline 
        \multirow{2}{*}{A}  & Col2 & ABCDE (Row1) \\ \cline{2-3}
        & Col2 & ABCDE (Row2) \\    \hline 
        B                   & Col2 & ABCDE (Row3)\\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Adding `\texttt` at row level didn't work. See below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|l|}
        \hline 
        \rowcolor[HTML]{CACFD2} 
        \textbf{Header 1} & \textbf{Header 2} & \textbf{Header 3} \\ \hline 
        \texttt{\multirow{2}{*}{A}  & Col2 & ABCDE (Row1)} \\ \cline{2-3}
        \texttt{\& Col2 & ABCDE (Row2)} \\    \hline 
        \texttt{\B                   & Col2 & ABCDE (Row3)}\\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

\end{document}

Adding `\texttt` at every cell level worked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|l|}
        \hline 
        \rowcolor[HTML]{CACFD2} 
        \textbf{Header 1} & \textbf{Header 2} & \textbf{Header 3} \\ \hline 
        \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{A}}  & \texttt{Col2} & \texttt{ABCDE (Row1)} \\ \cline{2-3}
        & \texttt{Col2} & \texttt{ABCDE (Row2)} \\    \hline 
        \texttt{B}                   & \texttt{Col2} & \texttt{ABCDE (Row3)}\\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

\end{document}

### Output

[image]

Comment: Please extend your piece of code to a MWE. What engine are you using?

Comment: "I need to change the font". Would this be the font size, weight, shape, or family? Or all of the above? Or something completely different maybe? Don't expect to find accomplished mind readers on this site. I'm afraid you'll be sorely disappointed if you do...

Comment: You can place your font commands inside each cell of the `tabular`.

Comment: I tried to use `\texttt`  at the row level, it didn't work.  But if I use it before `begin{tabular}` then it works.

Comment: please show us what did not work.  You will get much more help here if you extend your code to make a complete document that people here can just cut and paste locally and compile.

Comment: just use `\texttt` separately around each cell.  (although that is not Courier by default) Also delete the `\indent`  before the `\centering` which is not doing anything useful.

Comment: @Thruston I have edited the question and complete work is listed now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your suggestions, `\texttt` if applied at cell level works for me, I have entered the running code as well in the question. `\indent` has been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\texttt` separately around each cell.  a table cell is a group like `{...}` so there is no natural way to start a font change in the first cell in a row and make it last for the whole row.

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a command `\RowStyle` to specify formatting instructions for the current row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\small
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccl}[hvlines,colortbl-like]
    \rowcolor[HTML]{CACFD2} 
    \RowStyle{\bfseries}
    Header 1        & Header 2 & Header 3     \\ 
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=2]{\ttfamily}
    \Block{2-1}{A}  & Col2     & ABCDE (Row1) \\ 
                    & Col2     & ABCDE (Row2) \\  
    \RowStyle[color=blue]{\itshape}
    B               & Col2     & ABCDE (Row3) \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It's better to write `\RowStyle[color=blue]{\itshape}` than `\RowStyle{\itshape\color{blue}}` because the latter would not work in a column of type `p`, `m`, `b` or `X`.

The key `hvlines` draws all the rules.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on `tabularray`. There is an advantage of using it in tables with multiple cell/row/column definition, multiple fonts and colours etc. because it separates definitions from a content.

[image]

I am aware of a request to change only the second row. Simply change `row{2-3}` to `row{2}` for the desired effect (see [`documentation`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) for more info).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\definecolor{rowbg}{HTML}{CACFD2}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering

    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec = {ccl},
            row{1} = {bg=rowbg, font=\bfseries},
            row{2-3} = {font=\ttfamily},
            vlines, hlines,
        }
        Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
        \SetCell[r=2]{font=\normalfont}
        A        & Col2     & ABCDE (Row1) \\
                 & Col2     & ABCDE (Row2) \\
        B        & Col2     & ABCDE (Row3) \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```